# JSTREE: list not populating in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, jstree

On a success ajax call, I am dynamically creating a JSTREE inside a jquery dialog , I am getting the values to display on the console. but nothing appears on the tree. I tried some of the recommendations on the site but nothing seems to display the list.

```
success : function(data) {
      tmp7 += "<div style='width:600px;'>";
      tmp7 +="<br/>"; 
      tmp7 +="<div id='diagTree' style='width:200px; height:300px; float:left; background-color:white;'>";
      tmp7 +="<br/>";                                           
      tmp7 +="<div id='notetree' style='text-align: left'>";
      tmp7 +="</div>";                   
      tmp7 +="</div>";
      tmp7 +="<div style='width:400px; height:300px; float:left; background-color:white;'></div>";
      tmp7 += "</div>";
      var typelist = '<ul class="notetypelist">';
      $.each(data, function(key, val){
         typelist += "<li id='"+data[key].technicalid+"' name='nttype'"+counter+"' value='" + data[key].note_type + "'>" +techtype + "</li>";           
      });
      typelist += '</ul>';
      $("#notetree").jstree();
      //$('#notetree').html(typelist);
      $('#notetree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = typelist;
      $('#notetree').jstree(true).refresh();
      }

       var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div')); 
       $(newDiv).html(tmp7);
       $(newDiv).dialog({});
```

Comment: The `settings.core.data` property expects a JSON object and not html. Also the structure of the JSON data should be in a format that `jstree` understands.

Comment: Hi Stephen, the thing is it works out of the dialog, it is just inside the dialog that it does not display. So I am wondering if it is because of the place I am initializing the tree or something.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating a hidden dive on the html page, and then appending it to the dialog and enabling it. Took a hint for display using this link: [jQuery Append/Add Hidden div to jQuery Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479398/jquery-append-add-hidden-div-to-jquery-dialog)